# Enable External HTTPS is not visible for one domain

Tags: community, custom-domain, custom-url

I have 3 domains and pointing all the domains to the community, however I only get the option "Enable External HTTPS" for one domain. Can you please tell me why I get this option for only one domain.

Comment: What are the domains? What are the CNAME entires pointing to?